# How to prohibit localhost instance from eureka registration

Tags: java, spring, cloud, netflix-eureka

Is there is a way to filter the registration in eureka according to the URL?

For example to prohibit localhost instances.

Comment: Please show code and details of what you've attempted so far.

Comment: I juste configured eureka server with default configuration